# discord bot only detects messages when it is mentioned

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I made a discord selfbot that should detect every sent message and respond randomly to it. However, when I put it in a server with 450k people it only can detect those messages if they mention the account. This is the code

```
import os
import discord
import time
import random
import string
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "suwhgiowejvoifghoirwfofrgowegvofdgrovugdgovjfeogjrwo"

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='', self_bot=True, fetch_offline_members=False)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('connected to Discord!')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('message received')
    time.sleep(60)
    response=[
        'hi',
        'hello',
        'interesting',
        'no',
        'bruh',
        '.',
        'oof',
        'lol',
        'lmao',
        'yeah'
    ]
    try:
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(response))
        print('message sent')
    except:
        print("message error")
        pass

client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

The issue is probably just that there are way too many people and it won't work. However, if you think that it may be something else please let me know.
(I know selfbots are against the ToS and that my account could get banned please don't get pissed at me)

Comment: it might having something to do with self_bot. The docs mention that `If True, the bot will only listen to commands invoked by itself rather than ignoring itself. If False (the default) then the bot will ignore itself. This cannot be changed once initialised.` ~https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot

Comment: time.sleep(60) is blocking so instead you should use await asyncio.sleep(60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be with the `fetch_offline_members=False` or the `time.sleep(60)`, I can't think of sth else